# How to get means in LSMEANS in SAS 9.3

Tags: sas, proc, lsmeans

I am trying to get mean from the LSMEANS statement in SAS 9.3 but from the documentation on SAS website, it seams they have removed the means from default in the LSMEANS statement.

Per the documentation i am using ILINK option which is giving me "Mu", but that seem to be exactly same as my "Estimate"

Can anyone please help me on how we can get Mean in LSMEANS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which procedure?  GLM?  Logistic?

Comment: I am using proc genmod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think there has ever been a MEANS option in LSMEANS. Some procedures like GLM have MEANS statements in their own right, and I’m guessing that’s what you’re thinking of. In general, MEANS would often make no sense in GENMOD, which would explain why it is not available.